# Can I combine position: relative and float: left?

Tags: css

Can I apply both `position: relative` and `float: left` on one element? Like this:

```
div {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes.

[CSS2.1,  9.4.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning):

> "Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or *floated*,
>   it may be shifted relative to this position. This is  called relative positioning"

Comment: as stated below, you can do this, you have to be aware of the consequences though. For my case where i wanted to have an element in the upper left corner of the parent div no matter what, it is ideal. I use the element later in some JavaScript. For positioining, please see the caveat (nicely described) below

Answer (score 7):

The answers that claim that you can combine float and position are actually incorrect. Yes, the position of the floating div will indeed move, but the surrounding text will not flow as you expect. The problem is that the position attributes effectively leave a white box where the div that you're floating used to be, then moves the div elsewhere, leaving the box behind. Put another way, you'll be positioning your div on top of the text, when what you probably want is for the text to flow around the div in its new position.

Here's an example of a div that has a simple float:right

[image]

Here's an example of the same div, but with  position:relative; and top:.75in; added:

[image]

Note how the box is now sitting on top of the text. That's probably not what you want!

Comment: nicely explained, many thanks. So it is possible, one needs to be aware of the consequences

Answer (score 5):

> Could I apply position relative and float left on one element?

Yes. Try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I want to provide a different answer in case it may help someone. I had two side by side div's that I wanted them to take up space:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">stuff</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">other stuff</div>
</div>
```

I used to do this by applying `<div class="clear"></div>` after all my floating ones. This used to work because `.clear { clear: both; }` would solve the problem. This no longer works for me. Instead, [**I followed these instructions**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) and added this class to my container:

```
.noFloat {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto; //If you get a scroll bar, try overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
}
```

so I ended up with:

```
<div class="col-md-12 noFloat">...</div>
```

Here is a link to a bootply.com example: **http://www.bootply.com/EupCHRhV4s**

Answer (score 0):

yes, with [shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) + height 100% + pseudo-element

```css
/* container */
.two-box { display: flex; }
.two-box > div { border: solid 1px blue; }

/* border */
.two-box > div > .label::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 3em;
 height: 3em;
 border: solid 1px red;
}

/* float shape + text */
.two-box > div > .label {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 3em;
 shape-outside:
  polygon(
    0 33%,
    100% 33%,
    100% 66%,
    0 66%
  )
 ;
 border: dotted 1px yellow;
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
 /* vertical center text */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.two-box > .left > .label { float: right; }

.two-box > .right > .label { float: left; }
```

```html
<div class="two-box">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="label">L</div>
  L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="label">R</div>
  R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R R
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can use both.

You will use `float:left` to position element to left side and permit next element to position right side of this.

`position:relative` will affect itself and it's children, to take own position. when you will use `left:npx;top:npx` it will move this element left,right,top and bottom.

You can check this demo: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/g996vhpp/)

Comment: some one just down voting this answer, but not said what the wrong is....