# CSS bubbling while using jQuery Quicksand

Tags: jquery, css, quicksand

I'm using jQuery Quicksand to create a filterable portfolio of articles:

http://davekiss.com/new/

The problem is, when the filters in the sidebar paragraph are clicked (video, websites, motion graphics), the CSS is doubled on the articles that are being filtered and aren't properly positioned until the animation is complete. The plugin is adding `top: 60px; left: 416px;` to the first article in the filtered set, pushing everything over.

Keep clicking `website` to see the effect.

I believe this is the offending CSS, but I'm not sure how to adjust it so that it plays nice with the plugin:

```
article.project-container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

Visit http://razorjack.net/quicksand and click the filters (everything, applications, utilities) to see the intended effect.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official github page....

> Quicksand uses position: absolute to animate the elements. This means that the container can't use absolute positioning because it breaks Quicksand's calculation of coordinates. After I tried to disable position: absolute in your section.thumbs, Quicksand started to work flawlessly. And since your layout doesn't seem to need this kind of positioning (regular floats will do the job), this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your rule as follows:

```
article.project-container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px !important;
    left: 5px !important;
    margin: 5px !important;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

the `!important` declarations are used to override the plugin's rules.

(`background` is also re-written as specifying a shorthand for a single property is redundant).

Comment: were you able to get this working with this css? I tried plugging it in and the effect doesn't work as anticipated

Comment: also, the `float: left;` is necessary - i'm having multiple items appear next to each other, and it is valid css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635426/css-position-relative-and-float-left

Comment: yes, i was able to get this to work considering the state of the website at the time of the post, and assuming multiple items, the `float` does make sense.

Comment: the website is in the same state as before - the only edit has been the `article.project-container` to your suggested css

Comment: well, seems fine to me. you can be more descriptive as to what is the *desired result*.

Comment: sorry, please visit the plugin page: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/ and click the filters (everything, applications, utilities) to see the intended effect

Comment: no need to be sorry. please edit your question to contain these instructions.

Comment: try and replicate the conditions from the QuickSand demo: use `ul` and `li` instead of `section` and `article` - its not semantic anyhow, clean all added CSS, and so forth.