# Quicksand jumping in transition when filtering a portfolio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I updated my site to wordpress 3.8 and along with that came a weird jump when filtering the portfolio. inspecting this with chrome, it is very hard to see what exactly is going on. margins, padding, etc. are not being changed nor are elements being inserted. Other than this the effect/transition functions fine, and display correctly before and after the transition.
you can visit the page [here](http://www.bvh.com/wp-test/?page_id=2) to see the effect.FYI I already took a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553033/1463809) and this isn't the issue.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
This only seems to be happening in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

just add `overflow:hidden` to `li`